# Issues with while loop and reading from files

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm working on this project and I'm fairly new to C++. Its kind of hard to explain what I'm trying to do but I shall try. So I'm working with a file called flix.txt and in it  looks like the following:

```
1 A 5
1 B 4
1 D 3
1 F 5
2 A 1
3 E 3
3 F 1
4 A 2
```

The first column are people(my objects), second columns are movies, and the third are the ratings given by the objects.

I'm trying to first extract the first int from every line and create an object using an 'operator new'. Then I'm taking a movie and turning it into an int so I can plug the rating into an array. Sorry if it sounds confusing. Heres the code I have now:

```
//flix program

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#define NUMBER_OF_MOVIES 6

using namespace std;

int tokenize(string line);
int getMovieNum(char movie);
void resetPos(istream& flix);

class Matrix{
    public:
        int movieRate[NUMBER_OF_MOVIES];
};

int main(){

    int distinctCount = 0;
    int checker = -1;
    int check = 0;
    string line;

    int personNum;
    char movie;
    int rating;
    int movieNum;

    ifstream flix("flix.txt"); 
    ofstream flick("flix1.txt");

    //identify distinct account numbers in file    
    while(getline(flix, line)){
        check = tokenize(line);

        if(check != checker)
            distinctCount++;

        checker = check;
        check = 0;
    }

    //reset position in file
    resetPos(flix);

    //create objects in accordance with distinct numbers
    Matrix* person = new Matrix[distinctCount];

    for(int i = 0; i < distinctCount; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_MOVIES; j++){
            person[i].movieRate[j] = 0;
            cout << i + 1 << ' ' << person[i].movieRate[j] << endl;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    //reset position in file
    resetPos(flix);

    //get data from file and put into respective variables
    while(getline(flix, line)){
        flix >> personNum >> movie >> rating;
        cout << personNum << ' ' << movie << ' ' << rating << endl;

        //changes the char into an int
        movieNum = getMovieNum(movie);

        person[personNum].movieRate[movieNum] = rating;
    }

    //reset position in file
    resetPos(flix);

    //input ratings into movie array
    for(int i = 0; i < distinctCount; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_MOVIES; j++){
            cout << i + 1 << ' ' << person[i].movieRate[j] << endl;
            flick << i + 1 << ' ' << person[i].movieRate[j] << endl;
        }
    }


    //write data to text file
    //??

    flick.close();
    //free memory
    delete[] person;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int tokenize(string line){
    string myText(line);
    istringstream iss(myText);
    string token;

    getline(iss, token, ' ');

    int strInt = atoi(token.c_str());

    return strInt;
}

int getMovieNum(char movie){
    int movieNum = 0;

    switch(movie){
        case 'A':
            movieNum = 1;
            break;
        case 'B':
            movieNum = 2;
            break;
        case 'C':
            movieNum = 3;
            break;
        case 'D':
            movieNum = 4;
            break;
        case 'E':
            movieNum = 5;
            break;
        case 'F':
            movieNum = 6;
            break;
        default:
            movieNum = 0;
            break;
    }

    return movieNum;    
}
void resetPos(istream& flix){
        flix.clear();
        flix.seekg(0);
}
```

I also apologize in advance if there are noobish mistakes here.

I think the problem is somewhere in the while loop, that's where it keeps locking up. I spent hours on this and I can't figure out why it doesn't work. In the while loop, I'm trying to access every line of the file, snag the data from the line, take the movie char and turn it into an int, and then plug the data into the array within the object. When I did have it working, all the data was wrong too. Any input is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn to use GDB, it will be your best friend. Also this is c++ you need to drop all of the arrays and start using vectors and other stl types.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *locking up*?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this data after you read it in? You're making the job of reading the data a lot more difficult than necessary, but without some idea of how it's going to be used after reading, it's impossible to be sure of how to do the job correctly either.

Comment: @Devendra it crashes during the while loop.

Comment: @Jerry After the data is in, I want to copy it into another text file with the previous data, plus movies that people did not rate

Comment: Should look something like this:

Comment: @Arubix, does the program *always* crash? I tried running the code... I did not encounter a *crash*.

Comment: this comes out bad, not sure why 1 A 5
1 B 4 1 C 0
1 D 3 1 E 0
1 F 5...

Comment: @Devendra I'll try and rebuild it. Be back with results

Comment: @Devendra yeah it crashes for me still. I'm using DevC++

Comment: i tried your program i got some weird numbers but it dint crash. may be i can put up those. data displayed on the terminal is different and the ones in flix1 is different.on the terminal i got 1 A 5
1 B 4
1 D 3
1 F 5
2 A 1
3 E 3
3 F 1
4 A 2

Comment: @Koushik Weird, I'm not sure why mines crashing. Maybe its the files??

Comment: in the file i get this. 1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
2 0
2 0
2 4
2 0
2 3
2 0
3 5
3 1
3 0
3 0
3 0
3 0
4 0
4 0
4 0
4 0
4 0
4 3

Comment: it will not be the files.. could you edit your question and tell us what your expecting? take a 2 line sample and let us know what you expect from it

Comment: 1 more doubt, did your program compile properly? i'm asking because system() and atoi need stdlib.h or for c++ cstdlib.h but you dont seem to have included those..

Comment: there are going to be movies A thru F. So i need to output to a file the current ratings I have up top as well as the ones they did not rate. So since person 1 did not rate Movie E then I need to output to the file under 1 D 3 with 1 E 0 and so on for every other person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a little in your program and i'l paste only the changed part.
Somewhere after you reset the person[].movieRate[] to zero,you have written this while loop

```
resetPos(flix);
int k = NUMBER_OF_MOVIES + 2;  //this is the variable that i have declared
//get data from file and put into respective variables
while(k){      //do you see that instead of getline() i have used the variable k. i'l tell you why later

    flix >> personNum >> movie >> rating;
    //personNum = tokenize(line,1);
    cout << personNum << ' ' << movie << ' ' << rating << endl;

    //changes the char into an int
    movieNum = getMovieNum(movie);
    person[personNum - 1].movieRate[movieNum] = rating;  //this is personNum-1 and NOT personNum the most common mistake while indexing array.
    k--;
}
```

this code seems to work as your criteria.
the reason that i removed getline() is, if u call getline then the get pointer position will be incremented. so after this you call flix >> something... , this reads the data from the second line. your first line 1 A 5 is lost. this was the cause of the trouble. change it n let me know.

Comment: i have included stdlib.h for system() and atoi().

Comment: Yeah that was one of the problems too. Thanks for that. I couldnt find anything online about that. Maybe I was wording it wrong.

Comment: I also just figured out another problem that your answer gave me an idea about. I subtracted 1 from all the cases in the switch statement and now all the movies pop up in the right spot. Thank you again

Comment: Awesome. I figured it out. I took your idea but instead of using 'k' i used an int lineCounter that I added to the first while loop. When I did it your way, it only gave me the first six ratings. But you definitely provoked the solution. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me try to give at least some idea of a simple starting point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

struct rater {
    std::vector<int> ratings;

    rater() : ratings(6) {}

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, rater &r) {
        char movie;
        is >> movie;
        return is >> r.ratings[movie-'A'];
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, rater const &r) {
        for (int i=0; i<r.ratings.size(); i++) {
            os << char(i + 'A') << ":" << r.ratings[i] << "\t";
        }
        return os;
    }
};

int main() { 
    std::ifstream in("flix.txt");
    std::vector<rater> ratings(5);

    int i;

    while (in >> i) 
        in >> ratings[i-1];

    i=1;
    for (auto r : ratings) 
        std::cout << i++ << "-> " << r << "\n";    
}
```

Comment: I get a lot of errors when I run this but it might just be me. It looks good though. I dont know if you saw my comment up there cause I wasnt clear before. Im trying to populate the output file with ratings that people didnt rate as well. So person 1 didnt rate movie E so i would put after 1 D 3 something like 1 E 0

Comment: @Arubix: For some reason I didn't quite understand what you were getting at in the original comment, but it made more sense here. I've edited the code a bit to fit your needs a bit more closely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a clean up.  It uses `std::map` to keep track of the Person and Movie keys, which is more flexible as textual strings of any kind (sans whitespace) can be used.  You've added a comment saying you specifically want to list movies people didn't rate in their outputs - that can be done by using a `std::set` and ensuring each movie name encountered is inserted, then using an iteration over the set to guide lookups in each person's ratings: left as an exercise.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef std::map<std::string, int> Movie_Ratings;
typedef std::map<std::string, Movie_Ratings> Persons_Movie_ratings;

int main()
{
    if (!ifstream flix("flix.txt"))
    {
        std::cerr << "error opening input\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!ofstream flick("flix1.txt"))
    {
        std::cerr << "error opening output\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    Persons_Movie_Ratings ratings;

    std::string line;
    while (getline(flix, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        string person, movie;
        int rating;
        if (line >> person >> movie >> rating)
            ratings[person][movie] = rating;                
    }

    // input ratings into movie array
    for (Persons_Movie_Ratings::const_iterator i = ratings.begin();
         i != ratings.end(); ++i)
    {
        for (Movie_Ratings::const_iterator j = i->second.begin();
             j != i->second.end(); ++j)
        {
            cout << i->first << ' ' << j->second << endl;
            flick << i->first << ' ' << j->second << endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: C:\Users\havana\Desktop\Untitled9.cpp: In function `int main()':
C:\Users\havana\Desktop\Untitled9.cpp:31: error: 'const struct std::pair<const std::string, Movie_Ratings>' has no member named 'begin'
C:\Users\havana\Desktop\Untitled9.cpp:32: error: 'const struct std::pair<const std::string, Movie_Ratings>' has no member named 'end'

Execution terminated

Comment: Yes sorry... they should be `i->second.begin()` and `i->second.end()`. Main thing is whether you understand the changes and can develop it from there... if you can't fix these kind of bugs, the answer's no anyway....

Comment: Yeah, Im sorry. I stated above that im really new to C++. Sorry